# wshttpbinding support in silverlight 4

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wshttpbinding

Does silverlight 4 beta supports wshttpbinding (wcf)? If not, will it be supported in stable release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't look like it. Check out these blog post on the topic:

- [New Web Services features in Silverlight 4 Beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/archive/2009/11/18/new-web-services-features-in-silverlight-4-beta.aspx)
- WCF net.tcp Protocol in Silverlight 4

Silverlight 4 will support the NetTcp Binding, mostly for intranet scenarios - but I haven't heard anything about support for wsHttpBinding, sorry.

Marc

Comment: Any update on the final version of SL4? Does it support wsHttpBinding?

Comment: @Vitalik: No, SL4 support basicHttp as before, and now netTcpBinding. But that's all, as far as I know (but SL is not my core competency)

Comment: Thats too bad, it would be nice to reuse some existing wsHttp based services with our Silverlight app without having to create some sort of custom proxy for all of our calls.