# does Silverlight 4 support wshttpbinding?

Tags: wcf, silverlight

Now that the stable release is out, could someone please confirm if SL4 supports wsHttpBinding?
and also any feedback on netTcpBinding?

Comment: No, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854126/wshttpbinding-support-in-silverlight-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not - right now, it supports `basicHttpBinding` (as before) and `netTcpBinding` (new in SL4).